# How to convert JSON into php string

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have JSON data like this

```
["pdf","xlsx","docx"]
```

I want to change JSON to be like this

```
pdf,xlsx,docx
```

now i use this code, but i think this is not the best way

```
str_replace (array ('[', '"', ']'), '', $ jsondata)
```

please teach me the best way to convert JSON to be as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple try with `json_decode()` and `implode()`

```
<?php
$json = '["pdf","xlsx","docx"]';
$string = implode(',',json_decode($json,1));
echo $string;
?>
```

**Output:**

```
pdf,xlsx,docx
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/BEEsZ

Answer (score 0):

Use php built in `json_decode` and then `implode`

Like,

```
$str = '["pdf","xlsx","docx"]';

print_r(implode(",",json_decode($str)));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/aS0Vb)